# Exclude some of the "find" results

Tags: find

I'm using `find` command along with `-exec something` argument. Can I exclude some directories/name that match regex (something like rsync's `--exclude`)? Will `-prune` be enough if I want to exclude many things?

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude certain directories while using the find command under Ubuntu.

You can use the find command as follows to find all directories except tmp directory:

```
find /path/to/dest -type d \( ! -name tmp \) -print
```

Find all directories except tmp and cache:

```
find /path/to/dest -type d \( ! -name tmp \) -o \( ! -name cache \) -print
```

The `-prune` option make sure that you do not descend into directory:

```
find /path/to/dest -type d \( ! -name tmp \) -o \( ! -name cache -prune \) -print
```

You can find all *.pl find except in tmp and root directory, enter:

```
find /  \( ! -name tmp \) -o \( ! -name root -prune \)  -name "*.pl" -print
```

Taken from:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osx-bsd-find-command-exclude-directories/

Answer (score 1):

For a working solution (tested on Ubuntu 12.04).

```
find ! -path "*dir1*" -iname "*.mp3"
```

will search for mp3 files in the current folder and subfolders except in dir1 subfolder.

```
find ! -path "*dir1*" ! -path "*dir2*" -iname "*.mp3"
```

to exclude dir1 AND dir2.